# PHP Url redirection on index.php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am self learning php and started some coding for a web portal. I would like to develop the portal with url that should look like index.php?page=dashboard. If i put the dashboard.php in browser, it should not be displayed.

Queries that i have.

1.how to program to use pages like index.php?page=dashboard rather that having seperate php files like dashboard.php

2. How to make the url look like from www.example.com/index.php?page=dashboard to www.example.com/dashboard

Comment: You should google for .htaccess and how to get what you want. Then you can come back to show us what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Comment: @LelioFaieta The way I understand it he wants to know how PHP dynamic pages works AND rewriting. `how to program to use pages like index.php?page=dashboard rather that having seperate php files like dashboard.php` That's not just rewriting. That is basic php.

Comment: @PanamaJack you are right sir. Can you give me some good examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for that, i.e.:

Create a file named `.htaccess` on the root of your website and put the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ /dashboard.php [L]
```

This way, when a user navigates to `www.yoursite.com/dashboard` apache will redirect him to `dashboard.php` without changing the url.

Comment: But i have lot of pages like this. Do i have to do it in htaccess for all the pages?

Comment: You're welcome. You can use a regex for that. Google htaccess regex tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think reading this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) on URI components may help you in understanding parts of the URL.

Just in brief,

- ? denotes query/search send to server usually to query a database
- # denotes fragment or partials, not sent to server and is read by client side only.

If you can correct the question or with better examples to make it clearer.

ie. **index.php?dashboard** is not valid.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** Pedro Lobito has given a solution below, which hopefully is what you are asking.

Comment: @adrian-the, nice of you mentioning my answer. +1 for that and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new folder on your server/local and do a new index.html/index.php into it, so if a user opens www.example.com/dashboard/ it shows the url in the index but the user is on the index page.